# containerd pass incorrect hostPath from host

Tags: containerd

I try use hostPath in deployment, instead docker I use containerd (kubernetes version 1.21 and containerd version 1.5
, but creating pod failed with error, I guess may be I have some issue with config.toml of containerd

```
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/host_dir/config/services-config.json" to rootfs at "/app/config/local.json": stat /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/container_inside_dir/service/config/services-config.json: no such file or directory: unknown
```